# Webcasts/Podcasts temáticos

Tags: discusión, comunidad

#### Idea.

Hace tiempo que quiero consultar a la comunidad sobre la idea de realizar charlas (audio y/o vídeo) centradas en lenguajes de programación con los usuarios principales de las etiquetas de dichos lenguajes.

#### Temática.

Por desgracia sólo puedo hablar de mi etiqueta *favorita*: C++, cuyos usuarios principales podemos ver que serían:

- [[image] eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion).
- [[image]PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster).
- [[image]Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19610/trauma).
- [[image]Jose Antonio Dura Olmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/301/jose-antonio-dura-olmos).
- [[image]Elenasys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/elenasys).

Y por ejemplo, la temática sería tratar las novedades del lenguaje C++ y las opiniones de los ponentes al respecto.

En el caso de C++ el tema está al rojo vivo pues se planea la aprobación de un nuevo estándar para agosto de 2017 y podría hablarse de los cambios en el estándar, los cambios que quedaron fuera del mismo, los cambios que cada uno de nosotros propondría...

... y esto aplicado a otros lenguajes.

#### Organización.

La idea sería contactar con los usuarios principales, averiguar quienes estarían dispuestos a llevar a cabo esto (no todos van a poder participar ni todos van a **querer** participar) y acordar unas líneas generales de debate y unos horarios/temáticas.

#### Opiniones.

¿Qué os parece la iniciativa?

Comment: Yo digo que si... hay varias cosas que me interesaría saber / opinar de algunos lenguajes que conozco

Comment: me parece perfecto! vamos viendo si podemos juntar esta idea también: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/496/mentor%c3%ada-y-equipos-de-aprendizaje-grupal cuenten conmigo :D

Comment: Me parece una gran idea la de tener un webcast (o varios) donde se junta un grupito de usuarios para discutir sobre las tecnologías que les interesa.  Me apunto para moderar esas discusiones usando la plataforma de los webcasts.

Comment: ¡Me parece genial!

Comment: Es interesante una de estas charlas sobre cada lenguaje al menos una vez al año.